# Why using an array as an index changes the shape of a multidimensional ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a 4-D NumPy array, with axis say x,y,z,t. I want to take slice corresponding to t=0 and to permute the order in the y axis.

I have the following

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(120).reshape(4,5,3,2)
b = a[:,[1,2,3,4,0],:,0]
b.shape
```

I get (5, 4, 3) instead of (4,5,3).

When, instead, I enter

```py
aa = a[:,:,:,0]
bb = aa[:,[1,2,3,4,0],:]
bb.shape
```

I get the expected (4,5,3). Can someone explain why does the first version swap the first two dimensions?

Comment: This is a case of mixed basic (the slices) and advanced indexing.  It's described on the main indexing page.  The sliced dimensions are put last.

Comment: @hpaulj In the second example, the slices are not put last. Could you explain why or maybe provide a link?

Comment: It's the slice in the middle that triggers the reordering.  The link explains that there's a potential ambiguity that's resolved by placing the slice dimensions after.  I've seen arguments that this ambiguity doesn't really exist in the case where one index is a scalar, but apparently that's too hard to fix cleanly.  Fortunately your two step indexing bypasses that.  It may be messier, but shouldn't be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hpaulj mentioned in the comments, this behaviour is because of *mixing basic slicing **and** advanced indexing*:

```
a = np.arange(120).reshape(4,5,3,2)
b = a[:,[1,2,3,4,0],:,0]
```

In the above code snippet, what happens is the following:

- when we do basic slicing along last dimension, it triggers a `__getitem__` call. So, that dimension is gone. (i.e. no singleton dimension)
- `[1,2,3,4,0]` returns 5 slices from second dimension. There are two possibilities to put this shape in the returned array: either at the first or at the last position. NumPy decided to put it at the first dimension. This is why you get 5 (`5, ...`) in the first position in the returned shape tuple. Jaime explained this in one of the PyCon talks, if I recall correctly.
- Along first and third dimension, since you slice everything using `:`, the original length along those dimensions is retained.

Putting all these together, NumPy returns the shape tuple as: `(5, 4, 3)`

You can read more about it at [numpy-indexing-ambiguity-in-3d-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034413/numpy-indexing-ambiguity-in-3d-arrays) and [arrays.indexing#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing)

Comment: The second link you provide is indeed very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it useful 